# How to get inline or embedded JSON file data

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Can you please tell me how to get inline or embedded JSON file?

**Error:**

> polyfills.js:3 GET http://localhost:8100/data/questions.json 404 (Not
>   Found)

**Folder path:**

[image]

**survey-data.ts**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class SurveyData {

      constructor(public http: Http) {

      }

     getJson(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("data/questions.json") //not working here
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);

      }
}
```

**questions.json**

```
{
    "28903218": {
        "type": "group", 
        "prompt": "Cool, thanks! Now tell us about your child's day:", 
        "description": ""
    }, 
}
```

Comment: Put it in the www folder

Comment: Put it in assets folder

Comment: Can you tell me what is the path then here `this.http.get("data/questions.json")`? @peeskillet

Comment: It should work with /data/blah.json or if you want to put it n assets /assets/data/blah.json

Comment: Yes, It is working.Can you tell me why it works only when put under `www`? You can put it as an answer too.Thank you so much @peeskillet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `data` folder in the `www` folder. The reason it works is because the `www` folder is like the root of the "server". This is where static content is served from at runtime. Out of verything else in the src folder, only the `assets` folder is added to the `www` folder and the .ts files are compiled to a single entry point file and added to the `www/build`. In your case `data` does not get transferred. You can check the contents when you build.